# Determine $m$, for which each solution of $mx ^ 2 - (m ^ 2 - 3m + 2) x + 2m - 6 = 0$ is less than $2$.

Tags: calculus, quadratics

> Determine the value of the parameter m, for which each solution of equation $$mx ^ 2 - (m ^ 2 - 3m + 2) x + 2m - 6 = 0$$
>   is less than $2$.

I case when $m=0$:

$m=0\\-2x-6=0\\x=-3$

II case when $m\in R-0$:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\triangle>0\\x_1<2\\x_2<2\end{array}\right.$

Why can not I properly solve this equation?

Correct anwswer is $ (-\infty, 0] ∪ (1,5)$

Where is my error ? Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$?

Comment: $\begin{array}{l}\frac{m^2-3m+2-\left|m^2-3m-2\right|}{2m}<2\;\Leftrightarrow m\in R-0\\\frac{m^2-3m+2+\left|m^2-3m-2\right|}{2m}<2\Leftrightarrow m\in\left(-\infty,\;0\right)\cup\left(1,5\right)\\\end{array}$

Comment: It seems that you have the answer with those inequalities.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Why in correct anwser is $(-\infty, 0] ∪ (1,5)$, not $(-\infty, 0) ∪ (1,5)$

Comment: For what it's worth, $m \neq 0$, because otherwise the quadratic equation reduces to a linear equation.  So I am guessing the "correct" answer is indeed a typo.

Comment: Ohh wait.  When $m=0$, the solution to the resulting linear equation is $x=-3$, which is less than $2$.  So indeed the given answer is correct.

Comment: You have to special-case $m=0$ then add it into the range that $m$ can be in after you determine the rest of the range, since it is a zero of the denominator in the inequalities.